# Python Print Blank Line

Tags: python

Let's say I want to print a blank line at some point in my Python program.

My preferred way is simply:

```
print()
```

What about calling print with an empty string instead?

```
print('')
```

Is the second approach, print(''), as ugly as I think, or does it not matter? Does PEP-8 or any other well known Python coding standard address this?

Comment: Define "poor hygiene".

Comment: What is the question? Can you share more context?

Comment: @DonnyFlaw came up in a code review

Comment: You could always define an empty str and then call that variable to print

Comment: The empty string is unnecessary, sooo… omit it.

Comment: @PeterWood Good point, can be subjective. Wanted to avoid the use of the word style.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, both do the same thing.

Because a `print()` is always ended with a new line, regardless of what `string` you put in there.

But to avoid unnecessary code characters, I prefer the former.

Comment: `print` not **always** ends with new line but **by default**. It has `end` parameter which defines what to use as ending

Comment: @DonnyFlaw yes you're right. I should be more precise, regardless of what `string` you put in there.